# Как сделать первичный ключ одновременно внешним в Sequalize?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

Я разрабатываю приложение используя Node.js, Express, Sequalize и MySQL. Имеются следующие таблицы со связью один к одному [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что квитанция не может существовать без рассылки. Логика такая, что как только добавляется рассылка, добавляется и квитанция. Хочу сделать так, чтобы первичный ключ в квитанциях был одновременно внешним ключом и совпадал с первичным ключом в таблице рассылки. Я читал статью про MySQL и понял, что такое в принципе возможно. Но я использую ORM Sequalize и собственно вопрос, как это реализовать там.
Коды моделей:

```js
const Mailings = sequelize.define("mailings", {
  mailingId: {
    type: types.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
  },
  mailingType: { type: types.STRING, allowNull: false },
  dateOfSending: { type: types.DATE, allowNull: true, defaultValue: getCurrentDate()},
  status: { type: types.STRING, allowNull: false, defaultValue: "Отправлено" },
  linkOnReceipt: { type: types.STRING, allowNull: false },
});

const Receipts = sequelize.define("receipts", {
  idReceipt: {
    type: types.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    //autoIncrement: true,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
  },
  title: { type: types.STRING, allowNull: false },
  text: { type: types.TEXT, allowNull: false },
});

// Связь
mailings.hasOne(receipts, {
  sourceKey: "mailingId",
  foreignKey: {
    name: "receiptId",
    type: types.INTEGER,
    allowNull: false
  },
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
```

Имеем следующий результат по EER диаграмме
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, Sequalize всё равно автоматически добавил внешний ключ. Да и судя по линии связи, связь получилась один ко многим. Читал статью по Sequalize, там было сказано, что можно создать ассоциации с помощью полей, которые не являются первичными ключами. [Ссылка на эту статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/566036/)
Пробовал по этой статье, но ничего не вышло. В общем если есть люди, которые знакомы с Sequalize, то помогите пожалуйста.
P.s Можно ли реализовать эту логику с отдельно первичным ключом и внешним ключом для обеспечения связи квитанции с рассылкой (т.е. как получилось сейчас). Будет ли это являться правильной реализацией?

Comment: *Имеем следующий результат по EER диаграмме* А в SQL-коде это как выглядит?

Comment: Не могу сказать. SQL код не генерируется, я же ORM использую

Comment: Вообще мне активно не нравится разница имён. В структуре Receipts имя поля первичного ключа - idReceipt, а в определении внешнего ключа используется имя поля receiptId. Раз указываемое во внешнем ключе имя не существует в таблице - ORM его создаёт.

Comment: Суть в том, что я хочу, чтобы receiptId был и внешним и первичным ключом одновременно

Comment: Да ради бога... почему имя-то другое?

Comment: А, понял о чём вы, исправил, но получаю другую, уже системную ошибку. Вот текст Error: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key